# How do you prevent the classpath of subprojects to be included in the classpath of the top-level project?

Tags: sbt

I inherited a project that has a number of subprojects. During development, you can start the actual product by calling `run` on the top-level project. However, for running the product, you don't *need* the classpath of *all* subprojects to be included. In fact, some subprojects have a classpath that should *definitely not* be included in the top-level `runClasspath`. How can you do that? How can you explicitly exclude the classpath of a subproject from the top-level classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question first. I don't feel it's the right approach, but it seems to work. Suppose that you defined a subproject like this:

```
lazy val fooSub = project(....)
```

... then it seems to be possible to prevent the `fooSub`'s classpath to be included in the top-level classpath by adding this to the definition of your top-level project:

```
override def topologicalSort = super.topologicalSort.filter(_ != fooSub)
```

This works, because `fullClasspath` seems to use `topologicalSort` to find all subprojects, to include their classpaths to its own classpath. It seems a little too aggressive for my taste though. Hard to tell if it breaks somewhere else.